# AWS Amplify branch is missing functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

We're using a few Git code branches to manage the Amplify lifecycle (`dev`, `qa`, `pre-prod`, `main`) and have a working application on the `dev` branch. I can `amplify push` and it all works OK for dev.

There are 5 Java lambda functions in the codebase as well as their associated API Gateway endpoints.

I have git merged the codebase from `dev` to `qa` which seemed to go OK, but when I try and `amplify push` it only knows about one of the lambda functions; it doesn't even seem to want to push the other 4 lambda functions.

I have looked through and compared as many Amplify config json files in the project as I can see on the `qa` branch and can see references to all the missing lambda functions as well as see them referred to in the api gateway config folder.

I was trying to follow this : https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/teams/overview/

The process I followed was:

```
git checkout qa
amplify env checkout qa
git merge dev
amplify push
```

and it shows just one lambda function will be updated not all 5.

If I do an `amplify pull` then it deletes all the function code that is local (which I clearly don't want!)

My `amplify/backend/backend-config.json` contains an entry for each of the functions, as does the file `amplify/backend/api/tcsogatewayapi/cli-inputs.json`

If I do a `amplify function update` it only shows the one function - where does it look for the list of functions it knows about?

Anyone know how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

OK, so I tried a few things and this seemed to work; it was the `amplify init` that seemed to re-add all of the missing functions

```
git checkout qa
amplify env checkout qa
amplify pull
git merge dev
amplify init
amplify build
amplify push
```

Comment: This worked for me. What a dreadful product... looking to get off of amplify ASAP.